# How can I execute a cron job five seconds after the full minute?

Tags: bash, cron

Basically I am trying to execute the script '/path/to/my/script/script.sh -value 2' as 'testuser' at every minute's 5th second. (5 seconds is the delay required for "some reason" which could have been part of the script itself, but I just want to put it on Cron).

Is this the right way to do this?

```
* * * * * testuser sleep 5 && /path/to/my/script/script.sh -value 2
```

Comment: May be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331577/cron-jobs-to-run-every-5-seconds

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Yes it will.