# How to setup CRON job to run every 10 seconds in Linux?

Tags: linux, cron

I need to run a `CRON` job every 10 seconds from started time.

In Linux how to run a `CRON` job on every 10 seconds from the time its started?

I am trying to solve that as following: **when I make a request (or start) at 04:28:34 it should start at 04:28:44 not at 4:28:40**

This is what I have done

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/wget http://api.us/application/
```

What did I do wrong? Why does this not trigger `wget` every 10 seconds?

Comment: What should happen if a request is made at 04:28:34 and another request is made at 04:28:37 ? Do you need two requests in that case, or just one?

Comment: @DCoder its only one. request made at 04:28:34 should start at 04:28:44 not at 04:28:40

Comment: In that case, from the second request's point of view, the request is sent after 7 seconds, not 10. Is that acceptable? Should it keep repeating the request every 10 seconds until you shut down the server, or will it need to stop at some point?

Comment: @DCoder it should stop at the given time.

Comment: Use a shell script. cron is the wrong solution here.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

To elaborate on Sougata Bose's answer, I think the OP wants a command to be run every 10 seconds from a start time; not 10 seconds after the first minute and every subsequent minute.

cron only has a resolution of 1 minute (there are other tools I think that may have finer resolutions but they are not standard on unix).

Therefore, to resolve your issue you need 60 seconds / 10 seconds = 6 cron jobs, each with a sleep.

e.g. run crontab -e and add the following lines to your chosen editor:

```
* * * * * ( /usr/bin/wget http://api.us/application/ )  
* * * * * ( sleep 10 ; /usr/bin/wget http://api.us/application/ )  
* * * * * ( sleep 20 ; /usr/bin/wget http://api.us/application/ )  
* * * * * ( sleep 30 ; /usr/bin/wget http://api.us/application/ )  
* * * * * ( sleep 40 ; /usr/bin/wget http://api.us/application/ )  
* * * * * ( sleep 50 ; /usr/bin/wget http://api.us/application/ )
```

Comment: Not sure if this applies to Linux command line but in java7 and above the @Schedule spring annotation allows for resolutions up to the second. For example, this will fire your task every 10 seconds: 
`*/10 * * * * ?` 
Try adding one additional token to your expression and see if that works.

Comment: below answer is more elegant than this but thanks anyway.

Comment: cron generator https://codepen.io/04/full/YzYLPqr

Answer (score 48):

Another option is to edit your crontab with `crontab -e` and write:

```
* * * * * for i in {1..6}; do /usr/bin/wget http://api.us/application/ & sleep 10; done
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Next time, please add a bit more explanation to your answer.

Comment: Since the sleep is executed only after the command is finished, the interval may be longer than 10 seconds, depending on how long the command takes. This should be taken into account.

Answer (score 26):

`*/10 * * * *`    will run every 10 min.
`*/10 * * * * *`  will run every 10 sec.

You can checkout the [cron editor](https://crontab.cronhub.io/) for more options.

Comment: That does not work FYI. You will get an error

Comment: This does not work. Cron on Linux does not support this notation. crontab.cronhub.io is misleading, it does not state which platforms support this. This work on Mac but not on standard Linux server

Comment: thanks works great, fires exactly at 10 secs past min, 20 secs past min, etc - just what I needed

Comment: I guess this doesn't work on ubuntu systems

Comment: This answer is misleading, it does not work and WILL Not work on ubuntu systems as @NikhilVJ said. make use of https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Even though this question was for Linux, I came looking for something for `node-cron`, and it did work. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Using commas in seconds field works too:

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * *
```

Comment: This doesn't scare me as much as the other answers, it works and needs more upvotes.

Comment: It doesn't work on Linux, tested on Ubuntu 20.04 and it doesn't execute the job. As pointed out in other responses, maybe this works on Mac, and other job scheduling tools based on crontab notations but not the crontab for Linux.

Comment: doesnt work on linux

Answer (score 8):

Use `watch` instead; for example:

```
watch -n10 -x your_command
```

Answer (score 5):

If something should run every 10 seconds it does not have to be cron job. It can be a script with endless loop with sleep inside like:

```
while true
do
  # or whatever command you need to run
  rm -rf /var/www/some-directory
  sleep 10
done
```

and run it with

```
nohup bash my-endless-script.sh
```

which will run it on background and will continue also if you shut down the terminal.

You can kill the run with kill command.

Comment: The advantage of cronjob is that it provides a log file by default.

Comment: The downside, however, is that it can only run once a minute.