# What is the Cron Expression to trigger for every 62 seconds?

Tags: cron

Tried running job on even count with trigger  for every 31 seconds.

```
"*/31 * * * * *"
```

But it didn't help. The time difference between each schedule needs be 62 seconds.

```
    Expected:
    Scheduled  at 12:04:08
    Scheduled  at 12:05:10

                                       Allowed values    Allowed special characters   Comment

┌───────────── second (optional)       0-59              * , - /                      
│ ┌───────────── minute                0-59              * , - /                      
│ │ ┌───────────── hour                0-23              * , - /                      
│ │ │ ┌───────────── day of month      1-31              * , - / L W ?                
│ │ │ │ ┌───────────── month           1-12 or JAN-DEC   * , - /                      
│ │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of week   0-6  or SUN-SAT   * , - / # L ?                Both 0 and 7 means SUN
│ │ │ │ │ │
* * * * * *
```

Comment: what does this have to do with C#?

Comment: You'd want to set it to one minute and two seconds.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295868/how-to-setup-cron-job-to-run-every-10-seconds-in-linux?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a cron job every 72 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745901/how-to-do-a-cron-job-every-72-minutes)

Answer (score 0):

*/62 * * * * *

You can test it here: https://crontab.cronhub.io/

Comment: Thanks for the reply patrick. The allowed cron format for seconds i s 0-59.

Comment: Maybe this will help you, setting up multiple cron expressions, until you find the common denominator.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/745927/9697453